# Does the memory reference for an object in heap ever run out of space?

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory

I was recently going over a lecture for my college and a question popped in my mind. Since when we create objects with the new constructor, it allocates a memory space in the heap for that particular object. I wanted to know if it is ever possible for this allocated space to get filled up for any reason. For example, running operations on the object, an infinite-loop etc.
What do you guys think?

Comment: Are you asking if the heap can get filled up or if the space allocated for an object can get filled up?

Answer (score 1):

In a word, yes, it can. While the heap can grow and shrink, it does have lower and upper bounds (usually defined by the `-Xms` and  `-Xmx` arguments, unless you choose to se the defaults). If the heap size is exceeded, the allocation will fail and you'll get a [`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html).